# alpha-vantage Repeating Values in Stock quote requests

Tags: python, request

In my python code, I request stock quotes and it provides me 100 of them. At the end, I make a new request in a continuous loop, however, the values are the same as before. When I stop the program and run it again, they are able to change and I want it to do that when I make a new request in the loop. Here is the code below. I added a print statement to mark where the code loops back.

```
import socket
import requests
import json
import os
import time


url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"interval":"5min","function":"TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY","symbol":"MSFT","datatype":"json","output_size":"compact"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "use your own api key",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

while True:
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    result = response.json()
    if "Time Series (5min)" in result:
        print("beginning")
        values = result['Time Series (5min)']
        days =  values.keys()
        v = []
        for i in days:
            #v.append(float(values[i]['2. high']))
            print(values[i]['2. high'])
            time.sleep(1)   
    else:
        print("error, no data")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [API](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#daily) it says:

> By default, outputsize=compact. Strings compact and full are accepted with the following specifications: compact returns only the latest 100 data points; full returns the full-length time series of 20+ years of historical data. The "compact" option is recommended if you would like to reduce the data size of each API call.

So, it seems this call cannot be paged. Always only the last 100 are returned. Use for `output_size` `full` to get all (which can be a lot depending on the granularity requested with `interval` ). When you wait a while then obviously the last 100 values will have changed, but just within a few seconds the API might still return the last data, because there was no update, because you are just sleeping 5 ms, not minutes.